# Mule choice expression gives Stream Closed error

Tags: java, mule

I have below mule flow to convert xml messages to flat format and trnsfer then to ftp according to type of input xml file (Using choice).
But once I put a message it gives below exceptions. Can you guys please help to identify the problem.

```
<flow name="AWOutboundFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:\MuleTemp\DBS\outbound\aw\in" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <set-variable variableName="millis" value="#[System.currentTimeMillis()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <logger message="#[flowVars['millis']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/cw:Shipment/cw:TransportMode/cw:Code') == 'AIR']">
            <logger message="#[flowVars['millis']]: Classified to AW" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.chasoft.schema.UniversalShipmentData" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
            <transformer ref="AWShipmentOutbound" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
            <ftp:outbound-endpoint binary="true" host="localhost" port="21" path="/outbound/aw/out" user="DBS" password="502011" responseTimeout="60000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="aw_out_#[flowVars['millis']].dat" encoding="UTF-8">
                <reconnect frequency="10000"/>
            </ftp:outbound-endpoint>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/cw:Shipment/cw:TransportMode/cw:Code') == 'SEA']">
            <logger message="#[flowVars['millis']]: Classified to BL" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.chasoft.schema.UniversalShipmentData" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object"/>
            <transformer ref="BLShipmentOutbound" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
            <ftp:outbound-endpoint binary="true" host="localhost" port="21" path="/outbound/bl/out" user="DBS" password="502011" responseTimeout="60000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="bl_out_#[flowVars['millis']].dat"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[xpath3('/cw:UniversalEvent/cw:Event/cw:EventTime') != '']">
            <logger message="#[flowVars['millis']]: Classified toEVENT" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/xml" returnClass="com.chasoft.schema.UniversalEventData"/>
            <transformer ref="EventOutbound" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/>
            <ftp:outbound-endpoint binary="true" host="localhost" port="21" path="/outbound/event/out" user="DBS" password="502011" responseTimeout="60000" doc:name="FTP" outputPattern="event_out_#[flowVars['millis']].dat"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['millis']]: UNKNOWN Classification" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

Scratch of sample input file:

```
<UniversalShipment xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" version="1.1">
    <Shipment>
      .....
        <TransportMode>
            <Code>AIR</Code>
            <Description>Air Freight</Description>
        </TransportMode>
```

Exception:

> ERROR 2016-01-27 23:03:17,453 [[dbschenker].AWOutboundFlow.stage1.04]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>            Message               : Execution of the expression "xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/cw:Shipment/cw:TransportMode/cw:Code')
>   == 'SEA'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload
>   is of type: DeferredDocumentImpl
>           Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
>           Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>           JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
>           Payload               : [#document: null]
>
> Exception stack is:
>   1. Stream Closed (java.io.IOException)
>             java.io.FileInputStream:-2 (null)
>   2. java.io.IOException: Stream Closed (org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException)
>             org.mule.module.xml.el.XPath3Function:151 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleRuntimeException.html)
>   3. [Error: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed]
>           [Near : {... xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/ ....}]
>                        ^
>           [Line: 1, Column: 1] (org.mule.mvel2.CompileException)
>             org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer:438
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/mvel2/CompileException.html)
>   4. Execution of the expression "xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/cw:Shipment/cw:TransportMode/cw:Code')
>   == 'SEA'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
>             org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:232 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
>   5. Execution of the expression "xpath3('/cw:UniversalShipment/cw:Shipment/cw:TransportMode/cw:Code')
>   == 'SEA'" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload
>   is of type: DeferredDocumentImpl (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>             org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what's happening:

- Mule picks up a file and creates an `InputStream` from it,
- It evaluates the first `xpath3` expression and, or this, consumes the stream in order to read the file,
- It tries to evaluate the second `xpath3` expression and dies in a fire because the `InputStream` has been consumed, closed and can't be read anymore.

Solution: deserialize the `InputStream` in a `byte[]` before the `choice` message processor with an `<object-to-byte-array-transformer />` so its content can be read again and again in the downstream processors.

Comment: Thanks David for the help given. It's working as expected after applying the change suggested. I have seen lot of answers by you, but never thought you will directly help me on a question :-).